# Is there a way to savechanges from the DBSet

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm passing a DBSet as a parameter into a method, and also passing the `DbContext` so that I can call `SaveChanges()`.

Is there any way to call `SaveChanges()` or an equivalent on the DbSet object itself?

Comment: What is it what you want to accomplish exactly.. some more words to enlighten that would be great!

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a QA site and I simply asked if such a thing were possible. Admittedly there wasn't much research, but the question is clear and useful (to someone with my level of understanding at least)

Comment: @Bart I just wanted to know if such a thing were possible in order to formulate an approach. I don't (yet) have a specific problem that it relates to.

Comment: You can access DbContext using reflection as describe in [Can you get the DbContext from a DbSet?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17712575), but it's not recommended way

Comment: Thanks Michael, I didn't persue this in the end, but good to know there's an option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible without creating your own abstraction, such as a `Repository`. An instance of `DbSet` does not have a reference to the parent `DbContext`.

Comment: that's what I wanted to know. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

As qujck said, there is not any reference available to DbContext.
However, an individual Add, Remove operation result has a property called 'Context' which you can use to get hold of the DbContext which is tracking the DbSet.

Comment: *Which* `Add` operation has a "property" called Context?

Comment: var result = dbset<T>.Add(model). result variable will have Context property.